# How to cleanly extract a callback out of a when.js promise?

Tags: callback, promise, when-js

I need to pass a callback to a function whose signature is `function('ui', {foo: bar, callback: callbackfn})`. The function I want to pass is a When.js promise.

The best I've come up with:

```
var d = when.defer();
var p = when(d);
var q = p.then(function() {
    return loadItem(newCatalogItem, name, fileOrUrl);
});

ConfirmationMessage.open('ui', { callback: d.resolve });

return q;
```

This works (using a deferred to prevent immediate execution, and then passing the `resolve` function as the callback), but seems a bit convoluted.

Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: "*the function is a promise*" doesn't make much sense. Do you mean you have a promise for a function?

Comment: Does `ConfirmationMessage.open` use the node callback convention with error arguments? Or do you really want to fulfill in every case?

Comment: it either calls the callback with no arguments (success), or it doesn't call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to just [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) that `ConfirmationMessage.open` method (see also the when.js docs [here](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#node-style-asynchronous-functions) and [there](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#asynchronous-functions)), and then use it like a promise function, chaining `then` calls onto it.

For your specific example, that could be (using the portable promise constructor):

```
return when.promise(function(resolve) {
    ConfirmationMessage.open('ui', { callback: resolve });
}).then(function(confirmResult) {
    return loadItem(newCatalogItem, name, fileOrUrl);
});
```

Comment: Ok, nice. Unfortunately stuck with using when.js 1.7.1 (no `when.promise()`) but this helped structure it more cleanly regardless.